# Check if scrollview is scrolling

Tags: react-native, scroll

I have a scrollview in React Native and want to be able to detect if it is scrolling from its ref.

for example i want to see if it's moving due to momentum, etc. Is this possible?

Comment: you can add a properties called `onScroll` and it will call the function given to it whenever the `ScrollView` is scrolling.

Comment: See, I don't think so really. Sure, that will tell me when it starts, but it won't tell me when the momentum scroll ends.

Comment: Yea, it won't tell you about it. There's a separate props for that. it's called `onMomentumScrollEnd`. Aside from that I don't have any idea.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot but there is still a problem. I can check when the _momentum_ scroll is over, and separatley the _onDragEnd_ but I can't detect both it seems. e.g. if a user lifts the finger, but it's not fast enough to cause momentum scroll, onMomentumScroll end is never called. I want to know when the scrollview has stopped _moving_

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to detect for all `onMomentumScrollStart`, `onMomentumScrollEnd`, `onScrollStartDrag` and `onScrollEndDrag`

When the user is scrolling the scrollview (between `onScrollStartDrag` and `onScrollEndDrag`) then we assume it's moving. Similarly, if when the user has finished scrolling, it still moves with momentum, we detect scrolling there too.

So:
`(isScrollingManually || isScrollingWithMomentum)`
Tells us if the scrollview is scrolling or not.